# for the difference of apache ftpclient and sun ftpclient

Tags: java

I try use ftp client in my application

first one I use `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient`

but when running on linux server

can login to ftp server, can't get file list

return message is 425 Failed to establish connection.

if you close the firewall can be work

well, I try to change to `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient`

amazing thing happened

I can got file list

both are active modes, does anyone know why there is such a difference?

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect("host");
ftpClient.login("account", "password");
ftpClient.listFiles("path"); // can't work if you not open firewall

FtpClient ftp = FtpClient.create("host");
ftp.login("account", "password".toCharArray());
ftp.listFiles("path"); // even if you do not open the firewall can work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the relevant difference is that `sun.net.ftp.FtpClient` defaults to using passive (`PASV`) mode, but `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` defaults to active.

At least, that is my reading of the respective source codes:

- http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/ftp/impl/FtpClient.java#FtpClient.0passiveMode
  (line 79)
- https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html
  (line 491)

You should be able to confirm this by running:

```
FtpClient ftp = FtpClient.create("host");
ftp.login("account", "password".toCharArray());
ftp.enablePassiveMode(false);
ftp.listFiles("path");
```

You should be able to use PASV mode (aka local passive mode) with the Apache FTP client; see the [javadocs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply to your message,

I add ftp.enablePassiveMode(false); in my code,

but still can got the file list

Comment: but I add ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();, can work, thanks for your help

Comment: Yes.  As the javadoc explains, enablePassiveMode is for remote passive mode which is about server to server FTP.